# Integration measure in terms of the Levi Civita tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, integration

For a course in General Relativity I had to calculate the volume of the unit 2-sphere $S^2$, but I have some trouble with understanding the concept.

At first I calculated the volume of a sphere with radius $R=1$, but somehow this should only make sense when I'm in a three dimensional space. So my question is, is my calculation correct or do I indeed have to end up with the surface of the sphere.

The integral for  the volume is given by:

$$ V[M] \equiv \int_M \epsilon, \\
\epsilon \equiv \sqrt{ |g|} d^n x,$$

where $g$ is the determinant of the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ as defined in Carrol's "*Spacetime and Geometry An Introduction to General Relativity*".

Now I can calculate $|g| = r^4 \sin^2 (\theta)$ and plug this into the integral. Thus this gives me:

$$ V[S^2] = \int_{S^2} \epsilon = \int_{S^2} r^2 \sin(\theta)\ dr \ d\theta \ d\phi = \int_0^1 r^2 dr \int_0^{\pi} \sin (\theta) d\theta \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi=\frac{4 \pi}{3}$$

But I don't understand what the volume of the 2-sphere should mean and if this is the correct calculation. What I find especially confusing is the notation $ d^n x$

Comment: A 2-sphere is the "normal" sphere (which has a 2-dimensional surface). I am sure you know the volume of a sphere with radius $R$ by heart? Does it match your result?

Comment: yes it does match the volume of a sphere, but somehow if I'm on a 2 dimensional surface, the volume of this surface is not really something right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "volume" of a 2-dimensional space is what we would commonly refer to as the area. Note that for a 2-sphere we have $\epsilon = r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$, where $r$ is just a constant, usually taken to be unity. The integration thus yields
$$
\int_M\epsilon = r^2\int_0^\pi\sin\theta d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi = 4\pi r^2,
$$
or the surface area of the sphere.

To clarify: the differential geometric concept of volume is to be taken as a measure of the "size" of the space, regardless of dimensionality. Only in a 3-dimensional manifold does it correspond to what we in everyday life think of as a volume.

Comment: Thank you very much, sometimes this seemingly easy things can really confuse me. What I still don't really get is why then should $d^n x = d\theta  \ d\phi$. Is this because $dr=0$ by keeping it constant?

Comment: @DeanTheMachine Yes, or to be more exact: r is not a coordinate on the sphere, meaning that $dr$ does not show up in the wedge product $d^n x$.  If it did show up, then keeping it constant would mean that $d^n x = 0$. This is what would happen if we considered the 3-volume of the 2-sphere (obviously, the infinitely thin shell has zero 3-volume).